# Bash скрипт иморта mysql дампов из папки

Tags: vps, bash, mysql

Не силен в этой теме. Хочу написать скрипт bash для VPS (на CentOS), который по крону будет циклом перебирать файлы дампов в папке и импортировать их в базу, после импорта файла его нужно удалить...

Вот что делаю, но ерунда выходит:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql
use db_cars
cd / 
cd /home/admin/web/site/public_html/update/db/dump 
find  -type f -iname "*.sql" | while read FILENAME; do 
source $FILENAME
done
```

Comment: Может, проще будет сначала перейти в каталог, а уже потом импорт делать? И не через `source`, а через `mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DB_NAME < data.sql`

Answer (score 2):

Вы путаете командную оболочку mysql-клиента и bash. Нельзя писать одновременно и для одного и для другого. Вот как примерно должен выглядеть скрипт для bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/admin/web/site/public_html/update/db/dump 
find  -type f -iname "*.sql" | while read FILENAME; do 
    mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD db_cars < "$FILENAME" && rm -f "$FILENAME"
done
```